# Routing issues with Slim Framework running on AppFog

Tags: php, .htaccess, slim, appfog

I've been successfully running Slim apps on a couple different servers and tried setting one up on AppFog today using the same structure, but it isn't running normally.

I'll start with my directory structure:

```
.htaccess
/public
    .htaccess
    index.php
    /routes
/Slim
```

The **root .htaccess** file contains the DocumentRoot code from the AppFog docs.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^brs.aws.af.cm$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.brs.aws.af.cm$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/
RewriteRule (.*) /public/$1 [L]
```

The **/public** directory is where my api code will go, and the Slim **index.php** and **.htaccess** files currently are. The **index.php** file contains two simple routes:

```
require '../Slim/Slim.php';

\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();

$app = new \Slim\Slim();


// Default GET route
$app->get('/', function () {
    echo "Default GET route";
});


// Hello World route
$app->get('/hello/:name', function ($name) {
    echo "Hello, $name";
});


$app->run();
```

The server is setup at http://brs.aws.af.cm/ and I've listed the main routes below:

1. / => uses the default GET route
2. /hello/john => 404 Error
3. /public/hello/john => works, but requires "/public" in the url

And here's some extra weirdness. Seven-character routes result in a 404 error, six or less end up using the default GET route.

1. /123456 => shouldn't work, but uses the default GET route
2. /1234567 => 404 error

I'm completely stumped. I figure it has something to do with the DocumentRoot code, but I'm not sure what exactly. I've also tried setting

```
RewriteBase /public/
```

in **/public/.htaccess** but it doesn't seem to affect anything.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not familiar with AppFog, but have you tried eliminating your **root** .htaccess file and including those under the public directory's .htaccess?  Also eliminating the public RewriteRule and rewriting to index.php/$1

Comment: @GaryM Thanks. I tried your suggestions, however the **root** directory is technically the web root, so I believe that first .htaccess file is needed to actually redirect into the /public/ directory.

Comment: Just got the same problem with AppFog myself. Did you find a solution ?

Comment: Any solution to this also

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in the Slim PHP framework in Environment.php line 143. In particular, it assumes that the `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` path is compatible with `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` variable. In most cases this is probably true, however not when using MOD_REWRITE to hide an intermediate directory (as is happening in the .htaccess you quoted).

What's happening is `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` looks something like "/public/something..." but (because it is hidden), `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` looks like "/something...".

Slim is assuming the request URI is based on the script name, which is not the case here. I plan on notifying the Slim authors of the bug, but wanted to make note of it here as well.

You can fix/work around this by modifying Slim/Environment.php line 143 to this:

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) === 0) {
    $env['SCRIPT_NAME'] = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']; //Without URL rewrite
    $env['PATH_INFO'] = substr_replace($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '', 0, strlen($env['SCRIPT_NAME']));
} else {
    $env['SCRIPT_NAME'] = str_replace('\\', '/', dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])); //With URL rewrite
    $env['PATH_INFO'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
}
// $env['PATH_INFO'] = substr_replace($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '', 0, strlen($env['SCRIPT_NAME']));
```

At least that seems to work fine in my case. I believe the intention was to remove the path from the request uri, but that seems a pretty horrible way of doing it. If you need subdirectories to keep working you may need to do a bit more thinking. :)

Comment: FYI looks like someone else already reported this very issue: https://github.com/codeguy/Slim/issues/521

Comment: that's really useful, thanks.  You don't quite cover some edge cases that I added on github but they're trivial (if you public but not index.php or vice versa).

Comment: That solution doesn't work for me, I'm using this hack but I think there should be a better way:
http://help.slimframework.com/discussions/problems/5954-no-way-to-make-slim-work-in-a-subdir#comment_30893749